# vue-router: how to disable outline property of css of router-link as a

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-router

I want to disable outline of css in link element. I can disable outline of a by css class but I can not disable outline of `<router-link>`. How to disable outline?

```
.page-link, .page-link:visited, .page-link:hover, .page-link:active, .page-link:focus {
    outline: 0 none !important;
    border: 0;
}

<div>
    <!-- worked -->
    <a class="page-link">normal link</a>
</div>
<div>
    <!-- not worked -->
    <router-link to="" class="page-link">router-link</router-link>
</div>
```

browser:

```
Chrome
```

Comment: What are other classes/ styles added to the router-link?

Comment: 'page-link' only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.page-link, .page-link:visited, .page-link:hover, .page-link:active, .page-link:focus {
  outline: 0 none !important;
  border: 0;
}

<div>
  <router-link to="">
    <a class="page-link">normal link</a>
  </router-link>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid !important amap

```
.page-link, .page-link:visited, .page-link:hover, .page-link:active, .page-link:focus 
{
  outline: unset;
  border: unset;
}

<router-link to="" class="page-link">router-link</router-link>
```